# Reconstruct 3D graph with surf in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I usually use `surf` function to plot 3D figures in matlab, but now the data is different, so I am using `plot3` and I have the below figure. Do you have any idea how I reconstruct this figure to be more understandable even if by using different function. 
To be more concise, I have X values, with each X value there is a value of Y and value of Z.

[image]

```
X = [ 1 ;2 ;4; 8; 16; 32; 64];
Z = [ 1; 1.8 ; 3.46 ; 6.74 ; 13.18 ; 24.34 ; 39.33]
Y = [0 ; 56.92 ; 91 ; 109.95 ; 119 ; 123.57 ; 125.51]
fig = plot3(log(X),Y,Z,'b.-');
XLABEL=[  1 2 4 8 16 32 64];
set(gca,'XTickLabel',XLABEL);
set(gca,'XTick',log(XLABEL));

YLABEL= [ 0 30 60 90 120 150 180];
set(gca,'YTickLabel',YLABEL);
set(gca,'YTick',YLABEL);

ZLABEL= [0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55];
set(gca,'ZTickLabel',ZLABEL);
set(gca,'ZTick',(ZLABEL));
ylim([0 180]);
zlim([0,55]);

grid on
```

Comment: Hi, with the information you are providing the plot shown there could be perfectly right. If you have three vector size n of X Y Z that's a line in 3D.

Comment: But I am searching if there is a better way to represent it.. I usually using surf with colorbar for more understanding for range values of Z

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The plot is useless, you can't read any value out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to say, because we don't have a context. Common options are:

1. Plotting x/y and x/z in two separate plots. Precisely readable but difficult to get the connection between y and z. [subplot](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)
2. Plotyy, same as previous but in one plot. Y and Z values which correspond to the same x-value are aligned. [plotyy](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html)
3. Use a plot3 as shown above, but connect each point to the x/z plane. (details below)
4. Project the line on one or multiple planes and draw it there. (Plot the line again, setting x, y or z to 7 0 or 180, which is the location of your axis)
5. If two axis are of major importance, use a simple 2d plot and represent the third dimension using color/dotsize/annotations etc...

---

Code for Option 3:

At the end of your code, add the following code:

```
X2=[X';X';nan(size(X'))];
X2=X2(:);
Y2=[Y';Y';nan(size(Y'))];
Y2=Y2(:);
Z2=[Z';zeros(size(Z'));nan(size(Z'))];
Z2=Z2(:);

hold on
plot3(log(X2),Y2,Z2,'--')
```

To understand it, you have to know that matlab skips nans while plotting. Thus the code above generates a independent line segment for each point, connecting it to the ground plane.

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken. You mean connected all points corresponding to one of X values and Z as well. I tried
fig = plot3(log(X),Y,Z,'b.-');
Now,I have one line with connected points. Do you mean that or something else ?

Comment: @Carmen: No, I suggested other option. About which point are you talking? I will add an example if it's unclear.

Comment: I updated the question with my complete code, so it is easier to understand your suggestions based on the data.

Comment: @Carmen: Which of my suggestions is unclear but might be interesting? I will not provide code for all five.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in suggestion number 3, I tried it by the above code.

Comment: @Carmen: I added some code which is compatible to your data.